# Submitting a jar to sequenceiq docker-spark container

Tags: scala, apache-spark, docker, submit

so I never worked with Spark or Docker, but I have to use it for a project.
I'm trying to understand how this works. So I build a fat jar in Eclipse and was hoping to submit it to my docker container, which I set up using this guide: https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-spark

Now, I don't really understand how I get my jar from my local system to my docker container and then run it.

I think I'm missing how this all really works together, but maybe someone can clear it up.

I would be very thankful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know there are two posibilities:

**1,extend sequenceiq image and create your own docker image***

I think the best way is to "extend" sequenceiq spark docker image and `COPY` your spark application in the build phase of image.

so your Dockerfile should looks something like:

```
FROM sequenceiq/spark:1.6.0
COPY sparkapplication.jar sparkapplication.jar
COPY bootstrap.sh /etc/bootstrap.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/etc/bootstrap.sh"]
```

and you need to create/edit bootstrap.sh (entrypoint) with `spark-submit` command:

You can use [Their bootstrap.sh](https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-spark/blob/master/bootstrap.sh) and add here your spark submitting command (somewhere in the end of this file) something like:

```
$SPAKR_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
  --class MainClass \
  --master local[*] \
  /sparkapplication.jar
```

Just put your `sparkapplication.jar` nad `bootstrap.sh` next to `Dockerfile` (in the same folder).

**2, manually copy spark application to running container**

The second option is to use their docker container and copy application to container:

`docker cp sparkapplication.jar container:/sparkapplication.jar`

then `exec` (attach) to container (`docker exec -it container bash`) and execute `spark-submit` manually.